# Sum of odd numbers between 2 integers divisible by 7

Tags: java

I am using Java and want to find the sum of all odd numbers between 0 and 100, that are divisible by 7.

I got this:

```
public class odd7{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        int a;
        int b;
        int sum = 0;
        while(i <= 100)
        {
            a = i % 2;
            b = i % 7;
            if(a==1 && b==0)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

It's working perfectly fine, but I think it can be more shorter.

Thanks!

Comment: You are right. This can be shorter. If you're using Java 8, with Stream API it can be very very short!

Answer (score 2):

Starting at `7` and incrementing by `14` (to keep only the odd numbers):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 7; i <= 100; i += 14) {
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

(I understand it is kind of a hack but it is just a possible answer!)

Answer (score 2):

the smater way I'd come up with would be this:

- divide 100 by 7. and get the `abs` of it. This is he biggest multiplicand of 7 we could use.
- loop though all odd numbers starting by 1 until the number from the previous step.
- add all the results of current number x 7.

and as code:

```
int sum =0;
int maxFactor = 100/7;
for (int i = 1; i <= maxFactor; i+=2)
    sum += i*7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont assign it to two different variables a and b.

```
public class odd7{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        while(i <= 100)
        {
            if(((i % 2)==1) && ((i % 2)==0))
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the numbers which are 7 plus multiples of 14, so it can be much simpler:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (i = 7 ; i <= 100; i += 14 ) {
    sum+=i;
  }
  System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: @BalkrishnaRawool - you are right, I looked at his initial code and thought he meant even (since he's looking there for i%2==0). Fixed it now to 7 + multiples of 14

Answer (score 0):

Test with the code snippet below:

```
        int i = 7;
        int sum = 0;
        while(i <= 100)
        {
            if(i%7 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
            i += 2;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
```

It'll reduce nearly half of the iteration needed.